# azure cli mongodb connectivity

Tags: python, azure, azure-cli

```
No connection adapters were found for
'mongodb://abhi1:Hi4nVAY7YJOYj5iHcDLVMuWAavEgHzq43jXIObxbiNL3i8djOMjjD73P5PeWTcCNS0f#########jOrs4lvw==##############.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb'
```

i tried following solution to check whether this collection is exist in my azure mongoDB or not?

```
az cosmosdb collection exists --collection-name  "mycollection"
--db-name "mydatabase" -n "abhi1" --url-connection
 "mongodb://abhi1:Hi4nVAY7YJOYj5iHcDLVMuWAavEgHzq43jXIObxbiNL3i8djOMjjD73P5PeWTcCNS0f#########jOrs4lvw==##############.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb"
```

whenever i run some query on azure Cli for MongoDB i will get this error.

Answer (score 1):

`url-connection` is not `Connection String`.

You could find the value on Azure Portal.

[image]

The value should be like `https://<name>.documents.azure.com:443/`

You could use `az cosmosdb collection exists --collection-name -h` to get help.

You need modify your command like below:

```
az cosmosdb collection exists --collection-name  "shui" --db-name "test" -n "shui" --url-connection "https://<name>.documents.azure.com:443/" --key "dfZaM6mpM**********************xkFp334QlLJ6Q=="
```